# How to pass value from vue.js to controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

I have an array of values in vue.js, but problem is that I need to pass that values to controller. How can I do that, or is that a wrong way?

This is in my vue.js where I get values:

```
 additional_features: this.additionals_features

this.$http.patch('/profile/'+ user_id +'/property/'+ property_id +'/edit', property_credentials).then(function(response) {

                        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                        this.property_status = true;
                        this.property_success_update_message = response.data.successUpdateMsg;
                    } , function(response) {
                        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                        this.property_status = false;
                        this.property_errors = response.data
                    });
```

This is my controller

```
  $additional_features = $request->input('additionals_features');
```

This is my html:

```
<input type="hidden" v-model="property_credentials.additional_features" name="additional_feature[]" value="@{{property_credentials.additional_features}}" />
```

Comment: Can you not use AJAX?

Comment: i dont want to use ajax, because rest of app is in vue.js

Comment: You can’t. Vue is client-side, (Laravel) controllers are server-side. The controller has been processed and that process has ended once a response is returned to the browser and Vue.js (and any JavaScript) kicks in.

Comment: Hm,,, what do u advice me in this situation? Can i pass values from vue.js to view and then from view to controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [vue-resource](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource) and send it using post:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: {
        token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
        property_credentials: {
            additionals_features: [],
        }
    },

    methods: {
        submit: function() {
            this.$http.post('/your-api-url', {
                '_method': 'patch',
                '_token': this.token, // You must pass this token on post requests
                'additionals_features': this.property_credentials.additionals_features,
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The data will arrive directly in your controller, so you can probably

```
$additional_features = $request->get('additionals_features');
```

What you do with this data once it arrives in the controller, it's up to you.

Comment: i edited my answer...im using post request....but i can not save data in database

Comment: So what? You must use post (not patch) and send the _method to Laravel, and you should be good, that data will arrive in your controller as it is, and you don't have to save it in your database if you don't want to.